# qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1 installation on MACOSX El Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

Just got round to updating MacBookPro and trying to set up coding environment again. I am failing to 'make' qt, which I need to generate GUI's for pythonic programs. I have installed latest version of xcode, and after ~20hours of 'make' having followed installation proceedure on http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/install-mac.html the make routine bombs and I get the following:

FAILED: if [ ! -e ffmpegsumo.so -o ! -e ffmpegsumo.so.TOC ] || otool -l ffmpegsumo.so | grep -q LC_REEXPORT_DYLIB ; then /usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -Wl,-search_paths_first -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -Lgen/third_party/ffmpeg -arch x86_64 -L. -o ffmpegsumo.so @ffmpegsumo.so.rsp && { otool -l ffmpegsumo.so | grep LC_ID_DYLIB -A 5; nm -gP ffmpegsumo.so | cut -f1-2 -d' ' | grep -v U$; true; } > ffmpegsumo.so.TOC; else /usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -Wl,-search_paths_first -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -Lgen/third_party/ffmpeg -arch x86_64 -L. -o ffmpegsumo.so @ffmpegsumo.so.rsp && { otool -l ffmpegsumo.so | grep LC_ID_DYLIB -A 5; nm -gP ffmpegsumo.so | cut -f1-2 -d' ' | grep -v U$; true; } > ffmpegsumo.so.tmp && if ! cmp -s ffmpegsumo.so.tmp ffmpegsumo.so.TOC; then mv ffmpegsumo.so.tmp ffmpegsumo.so.TOC ; fi; fi

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib'

[5479/10912] CXX obj/src/3rdparty/chromium/v8/tools/gyp/obj/src/3rdparty/chromium/v8/tools/gyp/v8_snapshot.gen/v8_snapshot.snapshot.o

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

make[5]: *** [invoke_ninja] Error 1

make[4]: *** [debug-all] Error 2

make[3]: *** [sub-gyp_run-pro-make_first] Error 2

make[2]: *** [sub-core-make_first] Error 2

make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2

make: *** [module-qtwebengine-make_first] Error 2

Any helpful hints would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: So glennr was on the right track.  See my answer and let me know if it works for you.  Just finished the build on El Capitan, but I did it without webkit

Comment: Mind marking one of the two as an answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the OSX 10.11 SDK libz.dylib is not where the Qt build process expects it to be. This will need to be fixed in the Qt build system. A workaround is to symlink it from /usr/lib:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libz.dylib /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Helped a little.  Now I have: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/libresolv.dylib'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/libbsm.dylib'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/libcups.dylib'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the MacOSX 10.11 SDK has tbd files in place of the dylib files.  If you cat the dbd's it gives you the path where the dylib should be.

Anyway, it looks like glennr was on the right track.  You have to put in symbolic links to the dylib that are missing.  Building everything but webkit, it seemed to need libresolv.dylib, libbsm.dylib, libcups.dylib, and libz.dylib.

In terminal navigate to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib`

Then perform the following shell commands

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libcups.dylib
ln -s /usr/lib/libbsm.dylib
ln -s /usr/lib/libresolv.dylib
ls -s /usr/lib/libz.dylib
```

That should create symbolic links to the dylib in /usr/lib.

This seems to work when your building the library on 10.11 and targetting the same SDK.  I'm not sure it'll give you the right results if your running on an older or newer version, because then the version of the dylib may not match.